# Python marshal gives unexpected result for two level dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, serialization, marshalling

I'm using Python 2.7 and marshal 2 on OS X and I'm trying to serialize a two level dictionary of type:

```
{(1, 3): {(0, 1): 145, (1, 2): 101}}
```

I have an object `d` instantiated from a custom class used to store data, and the class includes a method `getRawData()` for returning data in the above format. Now when I first serialize the data with

```
with open('counts', 'wb') as f:
    marshal.dump(d.getRawData(), f)
```

and then deserialize it with

```
with open('counts','rb') as f:
    print(marshal.load(f))
```

something odd happens. The print is in this sort of format:

```
{(1, 3): {('\x00', '\x01'): 145, ('\x01', '\x02'): 101}}
```

Even more puzzling is, that if I create the dictionary to be serialized manually

```
 e = {(1, 3): {(0, 1): 145, (1, 2): 101}}
```

which gives

```
 e == d.getRawData()
 True
```

and then serialize and deserialize `e` the print is in correct format. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: What is `d`? What is the value of `d.getRawData()`?

Comment: d is instantiation of my custom class Data() and getRawData() returns a two level dictionary just like on the second row of my question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error (python 3.4.5, Linux, marshal version 4).

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.13 and marshal.version gives 2

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with Python 2.7.3 and marshal version 2, either. What does `print(d.getRawData())` display?

Comment: It's a rather long dictionary, starts `{(1, 3): {(0, 1): 145, (1, 2): 101, (0, 0): 135, (2, 1): 42...` When I created the dictionary manually `e = {(1, 3): {(0, 1): 145, (1, 2): 101, (0, 0): 135, (2, 1): 42...` I copy pasted the output of `print(d.getRawData())`

Comment: But it does not print `'\x00'` or `'\x01'`, does it?

Comment: No, that only comes after serialization/deserialization